# GCKMediaControlChannel returning an invalid request id on loadMedia: (kGCKInvalidRequestID)

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

Our app uses the `GCKMediaControlChannel` control media playback on the receiver.

The initial media load request is honored, the media plays to completion - however any subsequent request to load media ends in an error with the `loadMedia:` method returning `kGCKInvalidRequestID`

`NSInteger requestId = [self loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:autoplay playPosition:0];
  if (requestId == kGCKInvalidRequestID) {
    WARN(@"WARN loadMedia: the message could not be sent");
    return NO ;  // All subsequent requests go here
  } else {
    return YES ; // The first request to load media goes here
  }`

This *looks* like a situation where the GCKMediaControlChannel control channel might be out sync? We looked closely at the state of the Media Channel on the sender side and everything looks in order, with the sender acknowledging an "IDLE" status after the first media completes playback.

Not sure where else to look, the doc simply says of the `loadMedia:` method return value:

> The request ID, or kGCKInvalidRequestID if the message could not be sent.

Any clues as to what could possibly cause a `kGCKInvalidRequestID` to be returned by `loadMedia:`?

Comment: Could you NSLog the log output, and see if there is anything in there which clarifies? https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender#logging

Comment: Do you make intermediate requests? Maybe there is another request (even of another type, like `requestStatus`) that is being processed in that moment, so the channel is busy.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case, a conflict with the player state is what caused the `GCKMediaControlChannel` to return `kGCKInvalidRequestID`.

Unfortunately I can't remember the exact details, but I know that after going through the first media, the player was in a state not compatible with loading a new media, hence the error.
In other words, the issue had nothing to do with the state of the `GCKMediaControlChannel`, and everything to do with the state of the `cast.receiver.MediaManager` in the receiver.

Hope that helps someone!